# Fetching list objects from single document using Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have list of object store in single document in Firestore. On my android side i am not able to fetch list of object and their inner data.

Here is code i am trying to fetch data

```
        CollectionReference mCollectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Categories");

mCollectionReference.document("Dinner Dishes").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

        Collection<Object> objectMap = documentSnapshot.getData().values();

        for(Object result:objectMap){
            Sample obj = Sample.class.cast(result);
            HashMap<String, String> pic = obj.getPic();
            HashMap<String, String> name = obj.getName();
        }
    }
});
```

I need list of object i upload on Firestore in single document

My Model Class:

```
    public class Sample {

    private String name;
    private String pic;

    public Sample() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPic() {
        return pic;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You actually listed them as fields under document dinner dishes. That means you wouldn't be able to access it using Collection.

Comment: that way i reference it through document in collection

Comment: you could make them as subcollection which would make your life easier in my opinion.

Comment: You are right, but i am thinking about pricing, in sub collection they will count all the document but in this case document count as one read

Comment: okay I got your point now.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a java object, if that is how you saved it?

```
ObjectType myObject = document.toObject(ObjectType.class);
```

Comment: myObject is null everytime, i think this will work only for single object and i have list of objects.